# WP_List_Table default orderby is numeric

Tags: wp-list-table

I display a custom table using the `WP_List_Table` class. Everything works, but I want the default `orderby` to be numeric (by ID). If it is by string it works.

this is the function:

```
private function sort_data( $a, $b )
    {
        // Set defaults
        $orderby = 'id';
        $order = 'desc';
        // If orderby is set, use this as the sort column
        if(!empty($_GET['orderby']))
        {
            $orderby = $_GET['orderby'];
        }
        // If order is set use this as the order
        if(!empty($_GET['order']))
        {
            $order = $_GET['order'];
        }
        $result = strcmp( $a[$orderby], $b[$orderby] );
        if($order === 'asc')
        {
            return $result;
        }
        return -$result;
    }
```

The outcome is as this:

- 9
- 8
- 7
- 6
- 5
- 4
- 3
- 2
- 11
- 10

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the [`strnatcmp()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strnatcmp.php) for "natural" ordering, instead of `strcmp()` ([src](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25656625/2078474)) or handle the ID ordering specially, e.g. with typecasting and the [spaceship operator](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/combined-comparison-operator) `<=>` in PHP 7.

Comment: Yes, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks alot brother..